# Jqplot: Get the labels and x-axis ticks dynamically

Tags: jquery, grails, jqplot

I'm working on jqplot with groovy on grails. I am passing the data as a list and I want to populate the labels and x-axis ticks.
For one label it is working fine but how can I iterate?

```
             series:[ 
                {label:'${labelList[0]}'},
                {label:'aaa'},
                {label:'bbb'},
                {label:'ccc'},
                {label:'ddd'}
            ],
```

I am not using Json object. So any help for above problem will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I get you right you want to be able to set in your code a random number of labels right? You could use `JavaScript` to build array series and just set it to series of the graph.

```
var labelList = ["Label1", "L2", "Oi", "Bro"];
var series = [];

for(var i = 0; i < labelList.length; i++){
    var label = labelList[i];
    console.log("label = "+label);
    series.push({label:label});
}
for(var i = 0; i < series.length ; i++)
    console.log("series[i] = "+series[i].label);
```

[Here is working code sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/eDek4/)

Then in in your graph:

```
$.jqplot('chart', [data], {
   series: series
});
```

Comment: :Thanks for reply.What you told, works good.But I am getting that labelList as dynamic variable, so to access that I have to use ${labelList}. And in firebug I can see the variable interpreted as [aaa,bbb]. But it is not working.While if it is hardcoded as you said,then it works.reply will be appreciated.

Comment: Just like @Swap905 says please tell us more. Preferably if possible make a http://jsfiddle.net that represents the problem.

Comment: @Mark When I assign, var labelList = ${partnerList} then it gives me an error that,
   
    missing ] after element list [Break On This Error]  
    var labelList = [aaa, bbb]    
and points an arrow to 'aaa' in the list.

And when I assign, var labelList = '${partnerList}' that is vaiable single qoute then it draws chart but labels are assign like, every alphabet of 'aaa' as a different label, that is three 'a' labels .